# In "The Search" what was the first clue that things weren't right?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I'm just watching "The Search" where a treaty is apparently being signed with the Dominion.

What was the first clue that things weren't right?

My supposition: when 'Nechayev' called Sisko 'Benjamin'.
Because she knows Picard better, but she'd never call him 'Jean-Luc'! Of course, Sisko wasn't about to tell an Admiral how to address him (!) but this was still something Nechayev wouldn't do.

What else could have been a clue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, my point was did anyone notice any oddities apart from Nechayev calling Sisko 'Benjamin'.